# How to get Secondary Installer in Visual Studio 2015 Preview

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I was installing Visual Studio 2015 Preview. After the successful installation of visual studio I restarted the windows. After restarting it started a Secondary installer for install Android Sdk etc..., But it get failed unexpectedly by showing something went wrong error message.

How can I rerun the Secondary Installer. Do I need to reinstall completely.

Comment: IIRC, there was a message telling you how to do this during the installer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I got the Secondary installer location 
**"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\SecondaryInstaller"**, From where you can select the SecondaryInstaller.exe

Comment: I think you can also find it in add/remove programs.

Answer (score 1):

I got the secondary installer by windows search. the location is:
**C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\5FE48C2F034F5E6FA0D78333EBDF5D53C17A180A\packages\SecondaryInstaller**